# Lazy<T> Lazy loading error : A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lazy-loading

I am trying to use lazy loading for the first time to initialize a progress object in my class. However, I'm getting the following error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.

```
private Lazy<Progress> m_progress = new Lazy<Progress>(() =>
{
    long totalBytes = m_transferManager.TotalSize();
    return new Progress(totalBytes);
});
```

In .NET 2.0, I can do the following, but I would prefer to use a more up to date approach:

```
private Progress m_progress;
private Progress Progress
{
    get
    {
        if (m_progress == null)
        {
            long totalBytes = m_transferManager.TotalSize();
            m_progress = new Progress(totalBytes);
        }
        return m_progress;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That initializer would require `this` to be passed into a capture-class, and `this` is not available from a field-initializer. However, it *is* available in a constructor:

```
private readonly Lazy<Progress> m_progress;
public MyType()
{
    m_progress = new Lazy<Progress>(() =>
    {
        long totalBytes = m_transferManager.TotalSize();
        return new Progress(totalBytes);
    });
}
```

Personally, I'd just use the `get` accessor, though ;p

Comment: The lazy initializer can return null, and still be initialized. The property getter would in that case try to initialize again and again.

Comment: @wensveen no it won't: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/b547455bb4afe25cdae44d8cc78b8bdd

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant to say that when you use Lazy<T>, its valueFactory function can return null, but will only be called once.
However, when you have a property that checks a backing member for a null value, you either have to make sure that the backing member can never be null after initialization, or implement some other method to check whether the member is initialized or not: https://gist.github.com/mrwensveen/2bfd4d012171062f510400871e7a7419

Comment: @wensveen are you talking about the get accessor approach? Indeed. It wasn't clear - I thought you meant the Lazy-T callback